# How do I inject a property into a test JVM using Gradle?

Tags: java, testing, gradle, properties

I could easily exclude the class from execution using the build system which is Gradle but what I don't like about that is that it's silent. I want a failure that has to be fixed prior to check in.

So we use the naming convention of "*ITCase.java" for integration tests and "*Test.java" for unit tests. It's happened before that someone used "*ITest.java" which resulted in integration tests running in the unit test phase. We are suspicious that this has caused us some mysterious transactional issues during parallel runs. I want there to be a test that fails when this happens. Since we make copious use of parent classes, it would seem that we have some means for doing this.

An idea I've had is to inject a property into the test JVM so that I know whether the "test" task is running or the "integrationTest" task is running. Check that property and fail if it's wrong. Not sure how to do that with Gradle.

Comment: Depending on what testing framework you're using, what you want is probably your own test [runner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Runner.html). You can extend the default one, check the name of the test class with reflection and fail the test if it doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: I could be wrong but I'd prefer to avoid anything like Reflection which is liable to slow things down. This build already runs 1 hrs 14 mins. It's a very large project which is how we get this kind of thing.

Comment: Your testing framework is probably using reflection already, and I believe it's not the cause of a hour-long execution time. How many tests do you have? How many of them are integration tests? Are all tests run by one CI job? Are you running them all with every change?

Comment: Performance is being taken up in a different thread. Point is that we have something like 10,000 tests and over 100 subcomponents at 90% coverage last time I looked. It's big and needs to be performant or it impacts everyone.  ...but maybe Reflection performance has gotten better since the last time I used it. That would have been a gig where somebody was using it to set up test domain objects with read-only state. Can you imagine using it for every single test instead of mocking the objects?

Comment: Hmm... that brings up another point I had forgotten. They insisted on unit testing DAO's which IMHO implies the intent to put some logic in there that doesn't belong.

Comment: Aaanyway, I think you should give it a try. If you don't know how to implement it then please edit your question and add names / patterns with which tests should fail and I will implement it for you (: